# Error in blacklist.conf file: Ignoring bad line starting with

Tags: kernel, blacklist

I'm getting a black screen with the error shown in the below, even after deleting the blacklist.conf file. I located the four lines and I deleted them, but still it's showing the same error.

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 boot_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/ blacklist.conf line 58 Error in blacklist.conf file: Ignoring bad line starting with ´sudo´
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 boot_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/ blacklist.conf line 60 Error in blacklist.conf file: Ignoring bad line starting with ´modprobe´
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 boot_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/ blacklist.conf line 61 Error in blacklist.conf file: Ignoring bad line starting with ´/etc/rc.local´
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 boot_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/ blacklist.conf line 70 Error in blacklist.conf file: Ignoring bad line starting with ´exit´
/dev/sda6: clean, 477615/6283261 files, 8363443/25120256 blocks
```

Comment: I would ask you to show what's inside `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` but even without that I can say that something in there is very, very wrong. Why did you have those lines in the first place? Don't mess in `/etc` without knowing what you're doing, you can seriously mess up your system.

Comment: What is the content of your /etc/rc.local file? Cheers, Al

Answer (score 4):

Since you've deleted `/etc/modprobe/blacklist.conf` which is an important file. It tells Ubuntu to blacklist some problematic kernel module. So, I suggest you to reinstall the package `kmod` which provides that file. But you should reinstall it such a way that it will overwrite your modified changes.

To do so, use this command in a Terminal

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask" install kmod
```

This will ask you a question whether you want to retain your modified `blacklist.conf` file or want to overwrite it with the package maintainer's one. **You will select Y** here to overwrite.

Next you need to generate the initramfs using the command

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -v
```

Reboot, and the error should be gone.

---

**Edit:** I didn't consider it as an overkill to install `kmod` only for a config file because, this [`kmod`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/kmod) package is less than 100KB. Also It is better for a new user to directly restore the original version without copying from somewhere else.

Comment: Reinstalling is not necessary. It's just a file, which users can re-create

Comment: re-creating that long file is cumbersome for a user I guess, there were 57 lines and a new user shouldn't be burdened with that task @Serg

Comment: I cannot see what is cumbersome in just asking another user to copy and paste their default file. I could do that easily, just paste to pastebin. Big chunk of that file is comments and blank lines, so out of those 57 lines there's lots of unnecessary things

Comment: I could have given him in pastebin too. But think, which will be easier and more reliable?

Comment: But don't you think it's an overkill of a solution ? You're running reinstall   of whole package, just because of one config file that can fairly easily be replaced. It's like reinstalling firefox every time browser history gets corrupted

Comment: @Serg very good point. I would consider it overkill too, unless I knew it was only 98KB file

Answer (score 0):

Your four error messages add up to:

```
sudo modprobe /etc/rc.local exit
```

**sudo** is a command giving you root powers to run powerful commands.

**modprobe** is a tool that controls modules loading, unloading and kernel compatability.

**/etc/rc.local** is a file where you can put startup commands when you boot your system.

**exit** is used to end a group of commands which could be found in a file like rc.local and many other files.

Your blacklist errors don't pertain to any kernel loadable module at all.

After removing blacklist command errors you need to type in the terminal:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

This will generate a new initramfs with an updated blacklist for your next boot.

Comment: Whether or not those commands an in other shell files , it is irrelevant. What is important is that `/etc/modprobe.d/` files all are read by modprobe, so treat it as if config file for *that one specific command* (I mean modprobe). It only should contain information necessary for modprobe, is what i am trying to say here

Answer (score 0):

In the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` you must have only two things: the keyword `blacklist` and the name of the module that is **not** to be loaded at startup. ( In reality all `/etc/modprobe.d/` files are used by `modprobe` command, so they effectively can contain other keywords as shown by `modprobe.d` manual , but if it's a blacklist file, only use `blacklist` keyword and module name)

Here's example from my own file:

```
$ head /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf                                          
# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
```

Full file can be found here, on Ubuntu pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23101549/

Thus,whatever lines that you had there , `sudo modprobe /etc/rc.local exit` , they must be removed.